# Mongoid fields auto sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Everyone! I have a model:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

field :price1, :type =>Integer 
field :price2, :type =>Integer 
field :price3, :type =>Integer <== I want this field to be always result of price1 + price2
 end
```

My question is: How can I make :price3 to be always autofilled by sum of price1 + price2.
Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [callbacks](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html) interface. There are various callbacks exposed such as:

```
require "mongoid"
require "pp"

Mongoid.configure.connect_to("test")

class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :price1, type: Integer
  field :price2, type: Integer
  field :price3, type: Integer

  store_in collection: "mymodel"

  before_save do |document|
    document.price3 = document.price1 + document.price2
  end

end



model = Model.new

model.price1 = 2
model.price2 = 3

model.save
```

Which results in the "price3" field being set to the sum of the other two values.